# How can I "word wrap" a div within a container div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a comma separated "tag" type system, and I want the tags to scroll left to right, then go to the next line if the next tag would cause that line to be wider than the max width of the container.

I get different results if I use `<span>` or `<div>`

```
<span class="tag"><span class="tagspan" ></span></span>

<div class="tag"><span class="tagspan" ></span></div>
```

but neither one correctly wraps to the next line. ( If I use span it WILL wrap to next line, but it will break the tag in half and place the rest of it on the next line ).

Surely there must be an easy fix for this. I am trying to avoid having to calculate the width of each line and compare its current width to the width it would be if the next tag were added, then deciding if there needs to be a line break or not.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[JS Bin Here](http://jsbin.com/wasiv/9/edit)

jQuery:

```
$('document').ready( function() {
var value;  
var tag;
var cloned;
$('#tag').on( 'change keyup', function(){
value = $('#tag').val();
tag = value.split(',');
if (tag[1] != null && tag[0] !== ''){
cloned = $('.tag').first().clone().appendTo('#container');
  $(cloned).find('span').html(tag[0]);
  $(cloned).css({'opacity' : '1', 'width' : $(cloned).find('span').width() + 'px'}); 
  $('#tag').val('');

}
  if (tag[1] != null && tag[0] === ''){
  $('#tag').val('');
}

    console.log($('.tagspan').width() + 'px');
});


});
```

Comment: Not directly related to your issue but [here is an example of creating tags with UL -> Li and css](http://codepen.io/wbeeftink/pen/dIaDH).  Just a thought.

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit too quick before playing with the JS-Bin. You should calculate the width of each line; srys!

Comment: You can use float:left to your tag elements instead of the container and drop the display:inline-flex attribute which results in a line break if your tags reach the end of the line. Edit: change the outer span elements to divs for that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use float:left to your tag elements instead of the container and drop the display:inline-flex attribute which results in a line break if your tags reach the end of the line. Edit: change the outer span elements to divs for that effect.

// thanks Gary ;)

Comment: You could make the `.tag` class `display: inline-block` with no float and then you wont have to clear any floats. [Like this example](http://jsbin.com/cuweru/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks...floating on the tags instead of container!! Spent like three hours messing with it! :) Will ask stack overflow sooner next time

Comment: Thanks @misterManSam the white-space: nowrap I see there is very useful too. Guess CSS isnt my strong point.

Comment: @GaryHayes - You learn something new everyday with CSS ;) Also, if you are going to have a fixed height container, you may want to set `overflow-y: auto` on `#container` so that it will scroll instead of spill outside the box when it gets too many tags.

Comment: Aye I do... CSS can be a challenge sometimes. I just have the fixed height for development, testing, and debugging, which I like to do in jsbin because changes are instantly live. Once ready for use on site I will tweak the CSS for better appearance.

Answer (score 1):

This is more related to `CSS` styling than `JavaScript` code, I think I got it working just tweaking two classes in your `CSS` code:

```
span {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display: inline-flex;
  word-break: keep-all;
}
#container {
  text-align: left;
  display: block;
  min-width:400px;
  max-width:400px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

The thing is, span elements must fit into its parent element, that's why you should make children display inline and not its parent.

Working example: [Wrap span tags into DIV](http://jsbin.com/wihagozifixi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Given that you were working with flexbox, you might want to try add to your .container class flex-wrap:wrap; This acheives a similar effect.

Comment: Not familiar with flex box... that was just a desperate attempt :D

Comment: If you do go down the flexbox route see http://jsfiddle.net/AuroraArcade/3h8hqa9v/2/

Comment: I will keep this in mind too... may not use it right now, but added to my brain for later :D

Answer (score 0):

There are a few styles that are causing problems for you (referencing the JSBin you posted).  The following should fix your problems:

```
.tag {
    border: 3px ridge #336699;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 170, .25);
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #336699;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    margin: 2px;
    opacity: 0.0001;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

#container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

then adjust your JavaScript to the following:

```
$(function() {
    var value, 
        tag,
        cloned;

    $('#tag').on('change keyup', function(e) {        
        value = $('#tag').val();
        tag = value.split(',');

        if (tag[1] != null && tag[0] !== '') {
            cloned = $('.tag').first().clone().appendTo('#container');
            $(cloned).find('span').html(tag[0]);
            $(cloned).css({'opacity' : '1', 'min-width' : $(cloned).find('span').width() + 'px', 'display': 'inline-block'}); 
            $('#tag').val('');
        }

        if (tag[1] != null && tag[0] === '') {
            $('#tag').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

I've posted a functioning JSFiddle if you'd like to see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/autoboxer/opqcxm9k/

Cheers,
autoboxer